# How to get biddingStrategyConfiguration in Adwords API?

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I'm trying to retrieve the field 'biddingStrategyConfiguration' via Adwords API for Python (3) using CampaignService(), but I always get an weird error. It's weird because the field does exist, as mentioned in the documentation [found here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/selectorfields#v201809-CampaignService).

```
account_id = 'any_id'
adwords = Adwords(account_id) # classes and objects already created, etc.

def get_bidding_strategy():
    service = adwords.client.GetService('CampaignService', version = 'v201806')

    selector = {
        'fields': ['Id', 'Name', 'Status', 'biddingStrategyConfiguration']
    }

    results = service.get(selector)

    data = []

    if 'entries' in results: 

        for item in results['entries']: 

            if item['status'] == 'ENABLED':

                data.append({
                    'id': item['id'],
                    'name': item['name'],
                    'status': item['status'] # i have to retrieve biddingStrategyConfiguration.biddingStrategyName (next line)
                })

    return results
```

This is the error:

```
    Error summary: 

{'faultMessage': "[SelectorError.INVALID_FIELD_NAME @ serviceSelector; trigger:'biddingStrategyConfiguration']",
'requestId': '000581286e61247e0a376ac776062df4',
'serviceName': 'CampaignService',
'methodName': 'get',
'operations': '1',
'responseTime': '315'}
```

Notice that fields like "id" or "name" are easily retrievable, but the bidding configuration is not. In fact, I'm looking for the id/name of the biddingStrategies using .biddingStrategyID or .biddingStrategyName.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nevermind, I was just being foolish. You don't have to retrieve biddingStrategyConfiguration.biddingStrategyName, all you have to do is to retrieve biddingStrategyName only.

Comment: Can you update your code here? I was having the same issue and still cannot find out how. Thanks.

Comment: Look my edit about BiddingStrategyType, now works

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it: `biddingStrategyConfiguration` is not a retrievable field, but `biddingStrategyName` is (part of the JSON).

```
account_id = 'any_id'
adwords = Adwords(account_id) # classes and objects already created, etc.

def get_bidding_strategy():
    service = adwords.client.GetService('CampaignService', version = 'v201806')

    selector = {
        'fields': ['Id', 'Name', 'Status', 'biddingStrategyName']
    }

    results = service.get(selector)
```

Comment: It's BiddingStrategyName with capital B, in that case WORKS